# Google Sheet sum and multiply numbers based on dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to sum the packages(B) if dates are equal, then compare this sum with the Orders per Day column(C) and multiply by the Rate Per Package(D) depending where the sum falls within the Orders per Day number.

I would like to return just the total number if possible.

DEMO:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oSFnjogyXYybsqIYgQW2m45bbyAVBTKr3EVgxcGWFQo/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following 2 formulas

In cell `F2` place

```
=QUERY({A2:D},"select Col1, sum(Col2) 
                 where Col1 is not null 
                 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''",0)
```

Then in cell `H2` use

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS(G2:G>=80,G2:G*D9,
                  G2:G>=59,G2:G*D8,
                  G2:G>=39,G2:G*D7,
                  G2:G>=19,G2:G*D6,
                  G2:G>=14,G2:G*D5, 
                  G2:G>=9,G2:G*D4,
                  G2:G>=4,G2:G*D3,
                  G2:G=1,G2:G*D2, 
                  G2:G="",""))
```

*(You can adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)